# Purpose of CSMA and OFDM in WLANs

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, lan

Do wireless networks employ ***both*** Carrier Sense Multiple Access and Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing? If so, what are their corresponding roles? I'm not a professional and I am confused as to which of them makes P2MP communication possible. I always thought WLANs use CSMA to allow different nodes to communicate to the same access point on the same channel, but here I am reading about how every 802.11 standard uses OFDM as its **access** technology (except 802.11b which uses DSSS instead), allowing multiple devices to communicate with the same AP at the same time.

Is this the right place for PHY-related questions?

**EDIT:** changed TDM to CSMA to be more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found out that in Wifi, CSMA is the one used to allow **Multiple Access**. To be exact, IEEE 802.11 releases use CSMA/CA (Collision Avoidance) instead of CSMA/CD (Collision Detection) which is used in wired networks.

OFDM, on the other hand, is just an advanced digital **modulation scheme** which divides the data stream being exchanged between the node and the AP to multiple individual streams of lower rate and transmits them on different, closely-spaced carrier frequencies simultaneously (multiplexing). Making the signal more robust against error--thus allowing higher data rates--is what OFDM does in a nutshell.